# what is the cause of runtime error(other) in the following code

Tags: c, runtime-error

I was trying to solve a problem( http://www.codechef.com/BTCD2012/problems/DOORS) on an online judge. Following is the code for the problem.When i submit the judge gives runtime error(other).Am i using too much memory,if it is so then please help me out in finding other way,because memory has been used according to given constraints.

The constraint are as follow:

0< t1 <1000000;

0< num<100000000;

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a[100000001];
int main()
{

    int  t=3,j,k1,g,k=1,m,n=0,i,t1,num;
    for(i=1;i<10000;i++)
    {
        m=i*i;
        n=n+t;
        for(j=m;j<=n;j++)
        {
            a[j]=k;
        }
        k++;
        t=t+2;
        // printf("a[%d]--> %d\n",n,a[n]);
   }

   scanf("%d",&t1);

   for(k1=0;k1<t1;k1++)
   {
       scanf("%d",&num);
       printf("%d\n",a[num]);
   }
   getch();
   // return 0;
}
```

Comment: post the error. I just compiled your code and ran. It did get any runtime errors. I tried with t1=999999 & num=99999999

Comment: the code is working perfectly fine on my machine...no runtime errors....and also not failing on boundary condition but it is failing on online judge codechef.com. please help how to overcome it.

Comment: @arunmoezhi I notice that you tried to edit the question with some debugging edits. While the attempt to analyze sandyroddick's question is greatly appreciated, edits to questions are reserved for improvements to the question, not answers/corrections/clarifications to the question by third parties. I'd suggest putting your proposed code changes in comments or, if they're substantive, in your own answer, rather than editing the original poster's question. Thanks!

Comment: @sandyroddick: Did you get a seg fault? Please post the error log

Comment: @arunmoezhi : no i'm not getting any segfault...on the judge it is saying runtime error(other).

Comment: Can you try this option `ulimit -s unlimited`

Comment: @arunmoezhi how do we use that..i don't know about it.

Comment: @sandyroddick: http://jblevins.org/log/segfault

Comment: How many are you using for your "int"??

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
int a[100000001];
```

Attempts to allocate 381.5 MB of memory on the stack. This is most likely too large for the runtime to handle, so the program is being terminated.

Do you really need that many ints?

If you do really need that much memory, try allocating it in the heap instead:

change the global to a pointer:

```
int *a;
```

at the start of `main()`

```
a = malloc(sizeof(int)*100000001);
if(!a)
{
   printf("Could not allocate contiguous block\n");
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the new code on pastebin? It should not segfault.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[100000001];
```

This line is the problem, its allocating too much memory in static allocation area! As suggested, you could use malloc() to allocate this memory on the heap.

A much leaner way would be to use an array of **bits** [each bit representing a door, you just need to turn them on and off to represent open or close status of the doors]. It will be bit tricky to implement but your program will be much leaner (at least 16 times, a C int is at least 2 bytes, 16 bits) and much faster!

Comment: Since `a` is not defined inside a function, could you please explain how it will end up on the stack? Perhaps a reference to the standard?

Comment: you are right, a is allocated in the static allocation area, not the stack!

Answer (score 0):

Hey first of all good question :-) "+1" for that.
Now to your question,
Always a good practice to dynamically allocate the memory if you are sure that you need this much of them. Try `malloc`ing the `variable a`. How many bytes is your `int` using? And still better to use `unsigned long long` if you are sure that you do not need any `signed bits`.

```
unsigned int* a ;
a = malloc( sizeof(int) * 100000001 ) ;
```

The answers above and the comments are too very useful.

Comment: Try using "long long" for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

try this algo..:
Try to find out how many perfect squares between 1 and n..
prefect squares have odd number of multiples and i think that will be the ans..
suppose n=1000, there are only 31 perfect squares between 1 to 1000.
so,the number of open doors after she leaves= 31.

Comment: Are you sure this is an answer ?